# Radio button focus/select with TAB keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am stuck making radio button options change by keyboard with AngularJS. I need to have some kind of gray border while going through radio elements.

Is there anyone who has experience with that? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Could you provide a small amount of code? I don't know whether you're doing something weird like simulating the radio buttons with `<canvas>`.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML radio buttons, this is handled by the CSS pseudoclass [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus). By setting this to add a grey border, you should be able to show the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try custom css style. This example give you some idea about it.

```css
input:focus, input:hover{
    outline: 5px auto rgb(211,211,211);
    
 }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="group">Radio1
<input type="radio" name="group">Radio2
<input type="radio" name="group">Radio3
<input type="radio" name="group">Radio4
<input type="radio" name="group">Radio5
```